# Reactive services. Grouping and caching streams

Tags: c#, system.reactive

New: Entire source code with tests is now at https://github.com/bboyle1234/ReactiveTest

Let's imagine we have a view state object that is able to be updated by small partial view change events. Here are some example models of the total view, the incremental view update events and the accumulator function `Update` that builds the total view:

```cs
interface IDeviceView : ICloneable {
    Guid DeviceId { get; }
}

class DeviceTotalView : IDeviceView {
    public Guid DeviceId { get; set; }
    public int Voltage { get; set; }
    public int Currents { get; set; }
    public object Clone() => this.MemberwiseClone();
}

class DeviceVoltagesUpdateView : IDeviceView {
    public Guid DeviceId { get; set; }
    public int Voltage { get; set; }
    public object Clone() => this.MemberwiseClone();
}

class DeviceCurrentsUpdateView : IDeviceView {
    public Guid DeviceId { get; set; }
    public int Current { get; set; }
    public object Clone() => this.MemberwiseClone();
}

class DeviceUpdateEvent {
    public DeviceTotalView View;
    public IDeviceView LastUpdate;
}

static DeviceUpdateEvent Update(DeviceUpdateEvent previousUpdate, IDeviceView update) {
    if (update.DeviceId != previousUpdate.View.DeviceId) throw new InvalidOperationException("Device ids do not match (numskull exception).");
    var view = (DeviceTotalView)previousUpdate.View.Clone();
    switch (update) {
        case DeviceVoltagesUpdateView x: {
            view.Voltage = x.Voltage;
            break;
        }
        case DeviceCurrentsUpdateView x: {
            view.Currents = x.Current;
            break;
        }
    }
    return new DeviceUpdateEvent { View = view, LastUpdate = update };
}
```

Next, let's imagine we already have an injectable service that is able to produce an observable stream of the small update events for all devices, and that we want to create a service that can produce an aggregated view stream for individual devices.

Here is the interface of the service we want to create:

```cs
interface IDeviceService {
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets an observable that produces aggregated update events for the device with the given deviceId.
    /// On subscription, the most recent event is immediately pushed to the subscriber.
    /// There can be multiple subscribers.
    /// </summary>
    IObservable<DeviceUpdateEvent> GetDeviceStream(Guid deviceId);
}
```

How can I implement this interface and its requirements using the reactive extensions in the `System.Reactive v4` library, targeting `.netstandard2.0`? Here's my boiler code with comments and that's as far as I've been able to get.

```cs
class DeviceService : IDeviceService {

    readonly IObservable<IDeviceView> Source;

    public DeviceService(IObservable<IDeviceView> source) { // injected parameter
        /// When injected here, "source" is cold in the sense that it won't produce events until the first time it is subscribed.
        /// "source" will throw an exception if its "Subscribe" method is called more than once as it is intended to have only one observer and 
        /// be read all the way from the beginning.
        Source = source;

        /// Callers of the "Subscribe" method below will expect data to be preloaded and will expect to be immediately delivered the most
        /// recent event. So we need to immediately subscribe to "source" and start preloading the aggregate streams.

        /// I'm assuming there is going to need to be a groupby to split the stream by device id.
        var groups = source.GroupBy(x => x.DeviceId);
        /// Now somehow we need to perform the aggregrate function on each grouping.
        /// And create an observable that immediately delivers the most recent aggregated event when "Subscribe" is called below.
    }

    public IObservable<DeviceUpdateEvent> GetDeviceStream(Guid deviceId) {
        /// How do we implement this? The observable that we return must be pre-loaded with the latest update
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some weird code in that gist. Here's what I got working:

```
public class DeviceService : IDeviceService, IDisposable
{

    readonly IObservable<IDeviceView> Source;
    private readonly Dictionary<Guid, IObservable<DeviceUpdateEvent>> _updateStreams = new Dictionary<Guid, IObservable<DeviceUpdateEvent>>();
    private readonly IObservable<(Guid, IObservable<DeviceUpdateEvent>)> _groupedStream;
    private readonly CompositeDisposable _disposable = new CompositeDisposable();

    public DeviceService(IObservable<IDeviceView> source)
    {
        Source = source;

        _groupedStream = source
            .GroupBy(v => v.DeviceId)
            .Select(o => (o.Key, o
                .Scan(new DeviceUpdateEvent { View = DeviceTotalView.GetInitialView(o.Key), LastUpdate = null }, (lastTotalView, newView) => lastTotalView.Update(newView))
                .Replay(1)
                .RefCount()
            ));

        var groupSubscription = _groupedStream.Subscribe(t =>
        {
            _updateStreams[t.Item1] = t.Item2;
            _disposable.Add(t.Item2.Subscribe());
        });
        _disposable.Add(groupSubscription);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _disposable.Dispose();
    }

    public IObservable<DeviceUpdateEvent> GetDeviceStream(Guid deviceId)
    {
        /// How do we implement this? The observable that we return must be pre-loaded with the latest update
        if(this._updateStreams.ContainsKey(deviceId))
            return this._updateStreams[deviceId];
        return _groupedStream
            .Where(t => t.Item1 == deviceId)
            .Select(t => t.Item2)
            .Switch();


    }
}
```

The meat here is the `_groupedStream` piece. You group by DeviceId, as you said, then you use `Scan` to update state. I also moved `Update` to a static class and made it an extension method. You'll need an initial state, so I modified your `DeviceTotalView` class to get that. Modify accordingly:

```
public class DeviceTotalView : IDeviceView
{
    public Guid DeviceId { get; set; }
    public int Voltage { get; set; }
    public int Currents { get; set; }
    public object Clone() => this.MemberwiseClone();
    public static DeviceTotalView GetInitialView(Guid deviceId)
    {
        return new DeviceTotalView
        {
            DeviceId = deviceId,
            Voltage = 0,
            Currents = 0
        };
    }
}
```

Next, the `.Replay(1).Refcount()` serves to remember the most recent update then provide that on subscription. We then stuff all of these child observables into a dictionary for easy retrieval on the method call. The dummy subscriptions (`_disposable.Add(t.Item2.Subscribe())`) are necessary for `Replay` to work.

In the event that there's an early request for a DeviceId that doesn't yet have an update, we subscribe to the `_groupedStream` which will wait for the first update, producing that Id's observable, then `.Switch` subscribes to that child observable.

However, all of this failed against your test code, I'm guessing because of the `ConnectableObservableForAsyncProducerConsumerQueue` class. I didn't want to debug that, because I wouldn't recommend doing something like that. In general it's not recommended to mix TPL and Rx code. They problems they solve largely overlap and they get in each other's way. So I modified your test code replacing that connectable observable queue thing with a Replay subject.

I also added the test-case for an early request (before an updates for that Device have arrived):

```
DeviceUpdateEvent deviceView1 = null;
DeviceUpdateEvent deviceView2 = null;
DeviceUpdateEvent deviceView3 = null;

var subject = new ReplaySubject<IDeviceView>();

var id1 = Guid.NewGuid();
var id2 = Guid.NewGuid();
var id3 = Guid.NewGuid();

subject.OnNext(new DeviceVoltagesUpdateView { DeviceId = id1, Voltage = 1 });
subject.OnNext(new DeviceVoltagesUpdateView { DeviceId = id1, Voltage = 2 });
subject.OnNext(new DeviceVoltagesUpdateView { DeviceId = id2, Voltage = 100 });

var service = new DeviceService(subject);

service.GetDeviceStream(id1).Subscribe(x => deviceView1 = x);
service.GetDeviceStream(id2).Subscribe(x => deviceView2 = x);
service.GetDeviceStream(id3).Subscribe(x => deviceView3 = x);

/// I believe there is no need to pause here because the Subscribe method calls above 
/// block until the events have all been pushed into the subscribers above.

Assert.AreEqual(deviceView1.View.DeviceId, id1);
Assert.AreEqual(deviceView2.View.DeviceId, id2);
Assert.AreEqual(deviceView1.View.Voltage, 2);
Assert.AreEqual(deviceView2.View.Voltage, 100);
Assert.IsNull(deviceView3);

subject.OnNext(new DeviceVoltagesUpdateView { DeviceId = id2, Voltage = 101 });
Assert.AreEqual(deviceView2.View.Voltage, 101);

subject.OnNext(new DeviceVoltagesUpdateView { DeviceId = id3, Voltage = 101 });
Assert.AreEqual(deviceView3.View.DeviceId, id3);
Assert.AreEqual(deviceView3.View.Voltage, 101);
```

That passes fine and can be run without async.

Also, as a general tip, I would recommend doing unit tests for Rx code with the `Microsoft.Reactive.Testing` package, rather than time-gapping things.

Comment: very well done :) Sometimes a caller may call `GetDeviceStream` before any events have arrived for that particular deviceId, which case it will throw an dictionary-key-missing exception. How do we instead return an observable that doesn't have any events in it yet?

Comment: It was totally worth it sitting up all night pressing F5 waiting for your answer. Thank you so much.

Comment: Why was it necessary to put `RefCount()` on the end of `Replay(1)`?

Comment: Updated answer to support early requests.

Comment: `Replay(1)` returns a `IConnectableObservable` which is a weird animal. `RefCount` turns a connectable observable into a regular observable which is generally what you want. For more info read here: http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/14_HotAndColdObservables.html#PublishAndConnect

Comment: Now that you've updated the `GetDeviceStream` method, is it still necessary to have the dictionary? I figure all calls to that method could go through the `Where` method you have there.

Comment: Or did you leave the dictionary there for caching/efficiency? Is that the only reason it's there still?

Comment: It's more efficient as you say (changes `GetDeviceStream` from O(n) to O(1) where n is number of devices). If you wanted to get rid of it for simplicity, then you would have to put a replay on `_groupedStream`.

Comment: Do you need access to the gist to update it there to improve the quality of this question/answer for other readers?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198341/discussion-between-bboyle1234-and-shlomo).

Answer (score 0):

A huge thanks to @Shlomo for the answer above.

The implementation given in the accepted answer, whilst a magical education for me, had a couple of issues that also needed to be solved in turn. The first was a threadrace problem, and the second was performance when a large number of devices were in the system. I ended up solving the threadrace AND dramatically improving performance with this modified implementation:

In the constructor, the grouped and scanned device stream is subscribed directly to a `BehaviorSubject`, which implements the `Replay(1).RefCount()` functionality required to immediately notify new subscribers of the latest value in the stream.

In the `GetDeviceStream` method, we continue to use a dictionary lookup to find the device stream, creating a preloaded `BehaviorSubject` if it doesn't already exist in the dictionary. We have removed the `Where` search that existed in the previous implementation in the question above. Using the where search caused a threadrace problem that was solved by making the grouped stream replayable. That caused an expontial performance issue. Replacing it with `FirstOrDefault` reduced the time take by half, and then removing it completely in favor of the `GetCreate` dictionary technique gave perfect perfomance O(1) instead of O(n2).

`GetCreateSubject` uses the `Lazy` proxy object as the dictionary value because the `ConcurrentDictionary` can sometimes call the `Create` method more than once for a single key. Supplying a `Lazy` to the dictionary ensures that the `Value` property is only called on one of the lazies, and therefore only one `BehaviorSubject` is created per device.

```cs
class DeviceService : IDeviceService, IDisposable {

    readonly CompositeDisposable _disposable = new CompositeDisposable();
    readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, Lazy<BehaviorSubject<DeviceUpdateEvent>>> _streams = new ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, Lazy<BehaviorSubject<DeviceUpdateEvent>>>();
    BehaviorSubject<DeviceUpdateEvent> GetCreateSubject(Guid deviceId) {
        return _streams.GetOrAdd(deviceId, Create).Value;
        Lazy<BehaviorSubject<DeviceUpdateEvent>> Create(Guid id) {
            return new Lazy<BehaviorSubject<DeviceUpdateEvent>>(() => {
                var subject = new BehaviorSubject<DeviceUpdateEvent>(DeviceUpdateEvent.GetInitialView(deviceId));
                _disposable.Add(subject);
                return subject;
            });
        }
    }

    public DeviceService(IConnectableObservable<IDeviceView> source) {
        _disposable.Add(source
            .GroupBy(x => x.DeviceId)
            .Subscribe(deviceStream => {
                _disposable.Add(deviceStream
                    .Scan(DeviceUpdateEvent.GetInitialView(deviceStream.Key), DeviceUtils.Update)
                    .Subscribe(GetCreateSubject(deviceStream.Key)));
            }));
        _disposable.Add(source.Connect());
    }

    public void Dispose() {
        _disposable.Dispose();
    }

    public IObservable<DeviceUpdateEvent> GetDeviceStream(Guid deviceId) {
        return GetCreateSubject(deviceId).AsObservable();
    }
}
```

```cs
[TestMethod]
public async Task Test2() {
    var input = new AsyncProducerConsumerQueue<IDeviceView>();
    var source = new ConnectableObservableForAsyncProducerConsumerQueue<IDeviceView>(input);
    var service = new DeviceService(source);

    var ids = Enumerable.Range(0, 100000).Select(i => Guid.NewGuid()).ToArray();
    var idsRemaining = ids.ToHashSet();
    var t1 = Task.Run(async () => {
        foreach (var id in ids) {
            await input.EnqueueAsync(new DeviceVoltagesUpdateView { DeviceId = id, Voltage = 1 });
        }
    });
    var t2 = Task.Run(() => {
        foreach (var id in ids) {
            service.GetDeviceStream(id).Subscribe(x => idsRemaining.Remove(x.View.DeviceId));
        }
    });
    await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2);
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    while (idsRemaining.Count > 0) {
        if (sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds > 600) throw new Exception("Failed");
        await Task.Delay(100);
    }
}
```

See entire problem source code and test code here: https://github.com/bboyle1234/ReactiveTest